# Rotation in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, degrees

I have a rotation problem in Unity. I am reading degree values from file and I want to make a rotation around `x,y, and z axes`. However, degree values of rotation are changing when I used this code. The asset module Suited Man is making different rotations.

```
target = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z)
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startpos, target, Timer.fracComplete)
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Quaternion.eulerAngles`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) to get a Vector3 representation of the Quaternion and then convert the Vector3 back to a Quaternion using [`Quaternion.Euler`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html).

Example:

```
Vector3 rot = myTransform.rotation.eulerAngles;
rot = new Vector3(rot.x,rot.y+180,rot.z);
myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);
```

**UPDATE:**

This is my test code, the object is rotated on the Y-axis when I press the 'D' key.

```
public class BallControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform test;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Vector3 rot = test.rotation.eulerAngles;
            rot = new Vector3(rot.x, rot.y + 1, rot.z);
            test.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);
        }
    }
}
```

[Euler to Quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/steps/index.htm)

[Quaternion to AxisAngle](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/)

Comment: It did not work. Asset module did not rotate, it stayed constant.

Comment: My C# code is here. Thank you for answering.
Transform suitman = transform;
Vector3 rot = suitman.rotation.eulerAngles;
rot = new Vector3(rot.x,rot.y,rot.z);
suitman.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);

Comment: The problem is that y and z axes rotations are same direction and orientation.